# Completely Reseting Laravel 5 Migration Stuff?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration, laravel-artisan

To make a long story short, I have completely messed up my Laravel migrations on my local machine. They are 100% unusable.

I'm working with Laravel 5 for the first time, so I'm just messing with stuff and testing the waters, so to speak. Between manually tinkering with the database, rewriting my migrations, accidentally deleting a table or two (then the 'migrations' table itself [doh!]), I'm in this mixed-up state, and I just want to start all of the migration stuff over from scratch. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I'm currently stuck in a state where I can't do *anything.*

For example, if any remnants of old tables are still in the database when I perform `php artisan migrate:refresh`, I get a `Base table or view already exists` error message. However, if I delete all the tables, I get this error:

```
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message
'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'bsd_status.projects' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `projects`)' in 
path/to/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:620
```

I've run the following commands:

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan migrate:install
```

I'm not even sure I'm doing this stuff in the right order. Anyway, other than completely reinstalling Laravel, how does one get all his/her migrations back to "out-of-the-box?" Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried deleting the whole database, creating a new one and then simply running the migrations?

Comment: Delete migrations table, backup migrations folder and leave it empty. Now use package that generates migrations from database (search for it) and you are done.

Comment: its not "php composer dump-autoload" you just need to use "composer dump-autoload" in case of composer auto load

Answer (score 13):

What I liked to do is manually delete all the tables with what ever tool you use on your device.  For me I just use phpmyadmin.  After that I do.

```
php artisan migrate:install
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Don't know if this is the official way, but it works every time.

If you don't want to use phpmyadmin you can just 
login to mysql via command line

```
mysql -u root -p
DROP DATABASE laraveldb;
CREATE DATABASE laraveldb;
```

Comment: it works for me!! anyway, it would be awesome to have the backup of the official documentation, so i can rely on this method :)

Answer (score 4):

Although @Goddard's answer and @nozzleman's comment were both really helpful (I've used both suggestions several other times, so thank you), the solution had nothing to do with migrations. Well, … other than the fact that I screwed them up to begin with.

Anyway, nothing I did fixed the issue, so I put on my "think really f'ing hard" hat. After cursing for several minutes, I realized something. It appeared that — even when simply running `artisan` from the command line — any routes or providers I had set up were attempting to be "resolved" (or whatever the proper terminology is). Thus, I must have had a call somewhere attempting to get data from the missing table when the app started the bootstrap/init/start/run phase.

I decided to make sure I didn't have any weird things going on in my actual code, so I checked in my routes file (app/Http/routes.php) and all my Service Provider files (app/Providers/*) to see if I was trying to retrieve model data in any of them. Lo and behold, I opened app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php and found this:

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $layout = 'default';

    if ( Request::has('layout') ) {
        $layout = Request::input('layout');
    }

    view()->share('sharedAppData', [
        'layout' => $layout,
        'projects' => App\Project::all() // <- WTF, mate?
    ]);
}
```

If you recall, the table being complained about in the error messages was named "projects." Thus, I was attempting to get all projects at boot, so no matter what I did (at the command line or otherwise), nothing was going to work because my `Eloquent`-extended model (`App\Project`) was looking for a table that simply didn't exist anymore.

The moral of the story: Laravel is super complex, I suck at it, and no matter how many times I try to follow the teachings of the great Jeffery Way, I'll forever be a Laran00b.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 composer dump-autoload
 composer clear-cache
```

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your code, especially because other answers look completely different

Comment: I see that in other responses and work for me, I am not sure what files cleans exactly but it works.